# Call XSLT template recursion with key match

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml like this,

```
<categories>
    <data>
        <category_id>216</category_id>
        <children_sort_order>217</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>324</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>395</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>580</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>506</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>466</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>626</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>532</children_sort_order>
        <depth>0</depth>
        <description/>
        <name>Products</name>
        <path>products</path>
        <slug>products</slug>
        <state>live</state>
        <status>
            <state>live</state>
        </status>
        <updated_at>2016-06-09T05:13:08Z</updated_at>
        <westfield_locale>en_AU</westfield_locale>
        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
    </data>
    <data>
        <category_id>217</category_id>
        <children_sort_order>218</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>319</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>232</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>237</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>244</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>255</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>225</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>307</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>286</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>262</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>269</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>279</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>251</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>299</children_sort_order>
        <children_sort_order>292</children_sort_order>
        <depth>1</depth>
        <description/>
    <name>Women's</name>
        <path>products/womens-fashion-accessories</path>
        <slug>womens-fashion-accessories</slug>
        <state>live</state>
        <status>
            <state>live</state>
        </status>
        <updated_at>2016-07-12T03:35:17Z</updated_at>
        <westfield_locale>en_AU</westfield_locale>
        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
    </data>
    <errors />
    <meta>
        <api_version>1.3</api_version>
        <deprecation_information />
    </meta>
</categories>
```

I want to read the top level element and generate parent xml element then read the related category and insert as a child to first element. So the output should be like this

```
<Category category_id="216" name="Products" parent="0">
  <Category category_id="217" name="Women's" parent="216">
  </Category>
</Category>
```

I tried to apply recursive template with key matching but that did not work.

```
<xsl:key name="children-search" match="data" use="category_id"/>
    <xsl:template name="Category">
            <xsl:param name="parent"/>

            <xsl:variable name="current" select="category_id"/>

            <xsl:element name="Category">
                <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="category_id"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="code">1</xsl:attribute><!--<xsl:value-of select="sort_order"/></xsl:attribute>--><!-- Field is no longer provided in the Westfield Category Data -->
                <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="slug"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="displayname"><xsl:value-of select="name"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="desc"><xsl:value-of select="description"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="ismappable">1</xsl:attribute> <!-- Field is no longer provided in the Westfield Category Data -->
                <xsl:attribute name="order"><xsl:value-of select="sort_order"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="active"><xsl:choose><xsl:when test="state = 'live'">1</xsl:when><xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise></xsl:choose></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="parent"><xsl:value-of select="$parent"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>

            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:for-each select="children_sort_order">
                <xsl:call-template name="Category"><xsl:with-param name="parent" select="key('children-search', $current)"/></xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>
```

Please let me know if there is better way to approach this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need named templates with parameters here. Instead, if you have a template that matched `data`, you could then get the child elements like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="children_sort_ordesr">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children-search', .)" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Or better still (Thanks to Martin Honnen!) this..

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children-search', children_sort_order)" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:key name="children-search" match="data" use="category_id"/>
<xsl:key name="parent_search" match="children_sort_order" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="categories">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="data[not(key('parent_search', category_id))]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data">
     <Category id="{category_id}" name="{name}">
       <!-- recursive call -->
       <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children-search', children_sort_order)" />
     </Category>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the "parent_search" key which is simply used to pick the top-level `data` element (i.e. the `data` element which has no parent). You could perhaps simplify it to `<xsl:apply-templates select="data[1]" />` if the top level `data` element was always the first `data` element in the XML.

Also note the use of [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) to create the attributes on the `Category` element, which simplifies the XSLT greatly.

Comment: Why do you need the `apply-templates` nested into the `for-each`, why don't you simply use `<xsl:apply-templates select="key('children-search', children_sort_order)"/>`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I would expect that this applies templates to only the first node in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @Tomalak, https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-key says "When the second argument to the key function is of type node-set, then the result is the union of the result of applying the key function to the string value of each of the nodes in the argument node-set." so I don't see any XSLT 1.0 restriction to a single node argument.

Comment: Thanks for that! That was something I didn't know beforehand. I've updated my answer with this way of doing it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks, I didn't know that either. Unfortunately the output order will be document order (of the `<data>` elements), not argument order (of the `<children_sort_order>` node-set). Not sure if that makes a difference for the OP, but given the input it sounds like a dealbreaker.

Comment: @Tomalak, you have a good point about the order, I did not consider that when I made the suggestion to Tim. Let's see what the poster says, the snippets in the question unfortunately don't reveal the wanted output for most of the referenced items.

Comment: Could be fixed with a clever `<xsl:sort>`, but at this point a plain `<xsl:for-each>` will be simpler in comparison.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'm still testing with my data but it looks like it's doing the what I wanted.